# Grails - Minimum Installation for build

Tags: grails, build, grails-orm

We have a *defined* a platform environment that includes specific Java, Ant, and Subversion versions. The idea is that someone with this platform can checkout any project in our repository, run a build command, and can build that project without downloading any software, or doing any specific setup in order for the build to work.

This is mainly done for my personal convenience (after all, I defined this platform). I run the Jenkins server, and want to be able to build any project without going through a lot of conniptions. Jenkins should be able to do a checkout and build without any specific instructions or environment setup.

If a special product is needed, I usually ask that this product be included in the project's directory structure. For example, if a project depends upon Ant-Contrib to build, the `antcontrib.jar` should be in the project, and the `<taskdef>` should point to that jar in the project.

We have one Grails project, and I was hoping there was some way I could include a minimal Grails installation in that project just to do build. All I have to run are the following commands:

- `grails clean`
- `grails war`

I understand that for development reasons, you may need a complete Grails installation, but I'm just interested in the build itself.

I was thinking of installing Grails inside the project, but I downloaded Grails, and in the grails/dist folder, there are 33 *Grails* jars. Under the `lib` folder, there are 300+ jars. Under the `src` folder, there are another 33 *Grails* jars. That's a wee bit too much to include inside the project as part of a checkout just so I can do a build.

Is there a compact subset that can be used just to run the build?

If not, I'll have to install Grails on our build server. This isn't too much of an issue, but it does mean that anyone who wants to build this project must first install Grails. Plus, I'll have to document that this project needs a special installation and how it's done and all other dependencies.

Comment: My workplace is a bit of old school but we have achieved the same using Maven 2.2.1 and local Nexus repository. We need not have grails installed in the build server, the artifacts are automatically pulled over lazily. I use Grails 2.2.0 where the artifacts were broken down to smaller pieces like `grails-core`, `grails-hibernate`, `grails-i18n` and it becomes easier for Maven to pull the pom dependencies from `grails-dependency`.

Comment: Not to forget, `grails-maven-plugin` does the rest.

Comment: We use Ant/Ivy here, and we're connected to a Maven repository. Are you suggesting that Maven can do Grails builds? Or, are you saying that Maven can download all of those jars?

Comment: Maven builds can do both. Grails Maven plugin has to be used to induce the maven lifecycle in the grails app. Maven can also get the jars from the local m2 repo. To test the same, use grails' `create-pom` command in the app, you would get a pom.xml for your grails app. Browse through the same. I can provide a test project if required. Note: this is in context to Grails 2.2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of Grails is new enough (2.1 or newer), there is actually a built-in command to generate a wrapper script which can be used without having to have Grails installed, for exactly the purpose you mentioned.

The documentation says:

> The Grails Wrapper allows a Grails application to built without having to install Grails and configure a GRAILS_HOME environment variable. The wrapper includes a small shell script and a couple of small bootstrap jar files that typically would be checked in to source code control along with the rest of the project. The first time the wrapper is executed it will download and configure a Grails installation. This wrapper makes it more simple to setup a development environment, configure CI and manage upgrades to future versions of Grails. When the application is upgraded to the next version of Grails, the wrapper is updated and checked in to the source code control system and the next time developers update their workspace and run the wrapper, they will automatically be using the correct version of Grails.

See the complete docs here: http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#wrapper

Comment: Agree. Forgot to mention that in my response as well. Thanks for bringing it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a pom to mavenize my test grails app using `create-pom`. It looks like the below. Key items to note:

- Grails Version can be set which ever version you need. No need to install Grails. Maven would pull dependencies accordingly.
- Note the dependency item `grails-dependency` which would pull the essential items grails would need.
- Note the maven plugin `grails-maven-plugin` in the plugin section. This plugin hepls in running maven lifecycle in the Grails app.
- We also get the option to `fork` the JVM for this grails app build instead of overloading the JVM when required using maven.

Once all the essential dependencies are, all you need to create a WAR is to run `mvn install` provided Apache Maven is install in the build box.

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestGrailsApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>grails-app</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>TestGrailsApp</name>
    <description>TestGrailsApp</description>

    <properties>
        <grails.version>2.2.0</grails.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-test</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement />

        <plugins>
     ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
                <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${grails.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Whether for Fork a JVM to run Grails commands -->
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
.....

</project>
```